# ¿Por qué el compilador no detecta ClassCastException?

Tags: java

Sé que en tiempo de ejecución algo como esto podría generar una ClassCastException porque Object no es una subclase de String.

```
String [] test = (String []) new Object[5];
```

Pero quiero saber por qué el compilador no lo detecta.

Comment: El sitio es en idioma español, traduce tu pregunta, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Los que venimos trabajando hace años en esto hemos visto como cada vez los IDE nos ofrecen más ayuda, antiguamente todos los errores los veías en tiempo de ejecución.

Entonces creo que dependerá del IDE si es capaz de detectar ese error y no siendo responsabilidad del compilador ni del lenguaje. Y me parece que actualmente ninguno detecta esta circunstancia.

Creo que encontrar una respuesta 100% correcta a tu pregunta es algo difícil, se requiere un manejo acabado no solo del lenguaje sino que además de como funcionan internamente los IDE, por este motivo me atreveré a responder lo que yo pienso que pasa, pero con la advertencia que es una respuesta basada solo en la experiencia

Resulta que esta expresión es valida:

```
String [] test = (String [])Un_Array_De_Objetos;
```

Siempre y cuando `Un_Array_De_Objetos` sea inicialmente un array String y para saber ello debe ser comprobado en tiempo de ejecución

Por ejemplo esto es valido

```
String[] array = new String[] { "2", "2" };
Object[] Un_Array_De_Objetos = array;
String[] test = (String[])Un_Array_De_Objetos;
```

Y aquí viene mi suposición: Es que el IDE valida solo si los tipos son "casteables" sin evaluar el contenido del objeto, y como `Object` es casteable a `String` (en circunstancias correctas) no te marca el error, aun cuando según tu código es evidente que saltará la *Exception*

Por ejemplo `Object` no es casteable a `int`, y en este caso (por lo menos Eclipse) si detecta el error.

```
int [] test = (int []) new Object[5];
```